# matlab: how to solve this linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I have 2 vectors that are scalar multiples of each other but their components have an unknown 'z'.
ie

```
v1=[a, bz+c, e-zd ] 
v2=[e, fz+g, h+z]
```

Only `z` is a variable/unknown, the rest are just numeric coefficients. How do i solve this using matlab??

I tried using `linsolve` but it doesnt seem to support symbolic arguments (`z`).

Comment: better to enter numbers directly and let see

Comment: numbers are not pretty since i got these vectors through computations with matlab

Comment: look scalars means that $a=k*e$,$b*z+c=k*(f*z+c)$,$e-z*d=k*(h+z)$ right?

Comment: @dato: right. i hope i dont have to do this by hand ;)

Comment: no now look,i did not understand question if  $z$ is variable,it means that first  what you have to do it to find  scalar,which means that $k=a/e$,now  the same  $k=b/f=c/g$ they are all same,why you need to find z?after you will calculate it just  solve it  first by hand  then i  mean like this  $(b-f)*z=g-c$ and enter now in matlab

Answer (score 1):

$k$ and $z$ can be found fairly quickly by hand. However, since you are interested in formulating it using Matlab, let us consider that instead. The equations to be solved are

\begin{align}
a &= k e \\
b z + c &= k (f z + g) \\
e - z d &= k (h + z),
\end{align}

where $k$ is some unknown constant of proportionality. Note: Since $k$ and $z$ are both unknowns, this is no longer a system of linear equations; instead it is a system of nonlinear equations. To formulate this in Matlab, we can use `fsolve`. First let us reformulate the problem as follows. First

\begin{align}
a - k e &= 0 \\
b z + c - k (f z + g) &= 0 \\
e - z d - k (h + z) &= 0.
\end{align}

The system of nonlinear equations can now be formulated as solving the equation $\textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{0}$, where

\begin{equation}
\textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} a - k e \\ b z + c - k (f z + g) \\ e - z d - k (h + z) \end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \textbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} k \\ z \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

For example, to use `fsolve` to solve the above function, you could type

```
[x, fval, exitflag] = fsolve(@(x) [a - x(1)*e; b*x(2) + c - x(1)*(f*x(2) + g); e - x(2)*d - x(1)*(h + x(1))], [0; 0])
```

where the initial guess for the solver is `x0 = [0; 0]`, the solution (if it exists) is `x`, `fval` should be approximately equal to `0`, and `exitflag` describes if `fsolve` was able to find a solution (see [the `fsolve` help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#f477175) for more info). If there is no solution, then you might need to do some nonlinear optimization, but hopefully there will be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your system of equations can be written as
$$
V =
\left ( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & bz+c & e-zd \\
e & fz+g & h+z
\end{array} \right )
$$
where $V$ is a matrix `V = [v1 ; v2]`.

The first column of $V$ as well as of the right-hand side are irrelevant to finding $z$ (though the entries should of course match). Using $V'$ for `Vp = V(:, 2 : 3)` we get
$$
V' =
\left ( \begin{array}{ccc}
bz+c & e-zd \\
fz+g & h+z
\end{array} \right )
=
\left ( \begin{array}{ccc}
b & -d \\
f & 1
\end{array} \right )
~ z + 
\left ( \begin{array}{ccc}
c & e \\
g & h
\end{array} \right ).
$$
This matrix equation represents four different equations for $z$ which may or may not have the same solution. If not, there is no general solution.

The four separate solutions can be found in Matlab using element-wise division:

```
(Vp - [c e ; g h]) ./ [b -d ; f 1]
```

A solution exists if the four elements of the value of this expression are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* easily do this entirely symbolically in Matlab if your wish. Not with `linsolve`, but with [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html):

```
syms a b c d e f g h z k
v1 = [a b*z e-z*d];
v2 = [e f*z+g h+z];
s = solve(v1==k*v2)
```

It's possible since you seem to be using an older version of Matlab, that you may need to to call `solve` using the old string format:

```
s = solve('a=k*e','b*z=k*(f*z+g)','e-z*d=k*(h+z)')
```

In both case you'll see that `solve` returns three outputs as there were three equations.